# Do Semaphores block the calling thread or does the thread block itself?

Tags: multithreading

I am currently learning about Semaphores.
I know they are there to restrict access to ressources in a concurrent system.
f.e. in Java a Semaphore class has the methods `aquire()` and `release()` which calling processes will access.

Now in general, when a Semaphore has four spaces open and four threads try to aquire access, the access will be granted.
But if a fifth thread tries to access the resource the thread has to be blocked or set to sleep somehow. Do I as a programmer have to implement something like

```
if (semaphore.hasSpaceleft()){  
    semaphore.aquire();  
    ressource.access();  
} else {  
    sleep until semaphore.hasSpaceLeft();  
}
```

Or will the semaphore handle sleeping/blocking the calling thread?
(not only in Java but in general)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [according to docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire()):

> ```
> public void acquire()
>              throws InterruptedException
> ```
>
> Acquires a permit from this semaphore, **blocking until one is
>   available**, or the thread is interrupted.

<sup>*Emphasis mine*</sup>

---

Actually, your proposed program has a bug - a race condition - in it:

```
if (semaphore.hasSpaceleft()){  // 1
    semaphore.aquire();         // 2
    ressource.access();
} else {  
    sleep until semaphore.hasSpaceLeft();  
}
```

In the time window between `1` and `2` another thread might acquire the semaphore. That's why in general any semaphore implementation has to be designed around blocking acquire function. Alternatively, you can use [`tryAcquire()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#tryAcquire()) function:

```
if (semaphore.tryAcquire()) {
    resource.access();
} else {
    doSomethingElseInTheMeantime();
}
```

---

### What does "blocking" mean?

In general, operating system (OS) is responsible for scheduling threads. If a thread cannot acquire a semaphore, it is suspended by OS (i.e. it is marked as not eligible for running, so that OS scheduler ignores it when selecting threads to run) until semaphore can be acquired again.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand it. I'd like to have a general explanation on how they work and not just Java related.

Does the semaphore sleep the calling thread or does the calling process has to sleep itself?

Comment: @leslie the implementation of the semaphore will block the thread

Comment: @Leslie, in simpler terms, "blocked" means that the `semaphore.acquire()` function call _will not return_ until the resource has been granted to the caller.